# Rate for Sum of Random Variables

Tags: variance, moment-problem, rate-of-convergence

I Just read a Paper where we have $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ independent RV with zero mean.

And there were an Expression like
$$
Var = V + v
$$
where $V:= \sum_{1=j}^n \sum_{1=i}^nE(X_j^2)E(X_i^2)$

and $v:= \sum_{1=i}^n(E(X_i^4)-3E(X_i^2)^2)$

And it was said that it is easy to show that v=o(V), so that for $n \to \infty$, $v$ is negligible.

But I have no idea how to handle the term $E(X^4)$ in generel.

Comment: How is Var defined in this case?

Comment: its the variance of ||A*X||. So in the sums are some constants missing, but i guess they wont play any role here. But if it helps i can write the exact form of everything

Comment: yes it would help.

Comment: http://www.wias-berlin.de/people/spokoiny/publications/6_Spokoiny_a2_01/atest.pdf

here is the link and my question is at the end of page 7

Comment: thank u very much for your help btw :)

Comment: So your question is, how to show that $v=o(V)$ ? The variance of $ ||W_h \varepsilon||^2$ is standard calculation, i assume that part is clear?

Comment: yes that is my question :)

Comment: Well, looking at the context, what the authors mean is that $V$ has $n^2$ terms, while $v$ has only $n$ terms, so in the limit $n\to \infty$, $V$ is going to dominate.

Comment: mhh doesn`t it depend also on the therms $\sigma^2(X_i)$ and $S_4(X_i)$? cause maybe $\sigma^2(X_i)$ could shrink like $1/i^{10}$ and $S_4(X_i)$ like 1/i for example?

Comment: If $\mathbb E X^k<\infty$, then $\lim_n n^{(k-r)/2} \mathbb E[X^r {\bf 1}(|X|<\sqrt n)] =$, for any $r\geq k+1$. $\mathbb E[X^4] = \mathbb E[X^4 {\bf 1}(|X|<\sqrt n] + \mathbb E[X^4 {\bf 1}(|X| \geq \sqrt n)]$. If $\mathbb EX^4<\infty$ then the rightmost term converges to 0. I believe that this lemma helps, with the right modifications.

Comment: in the first equation, what is on the right side of the equation?

Comment: But thank you so much for these tips :) Have a nice day!

Comment: Oh, it should be 0.